# Amazon Redshift mechanism for aggregating a column into a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, group-concat, amazon-redshift

Amazon Redshift is based on ParAccel which is loosely based on Postgres 8.1 but without array and set functions, UDFs, regular expressions and a whole lot of other useful functionality.

I am looking for a way to aggregate a column into a string. Many solutions exist for other databases but they use array functions (Postgres 8.x), `string_agg` (Postgres 9.0) or `GROUP_CONCAT` (MySQL). Any ideas how to make this happen on Redshift?

```
-- How does this become '1,2,3'?
select 1 as x
union all select 2
union all select 3
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208885/alternative-to-group-concat-in-redshift) relates to the lack of support for group_concat in Redshift but it's answer is not about a group_concat alternative but about how to pick random attributes from a group, which is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Use the client application? Use a smarter database? If you've got no `array_agg` and `array_to_string`, and no `string_agg`, and no functions to write a user-defined aggregate, you're stuffed. (Doesn't Amazon's Redshift team have support for this sort of thing? They should at the prices they charge for Redshift).